# Removing duplicate observations in SparkR DataFrame

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I have a SparkR `DataFrame` with duplicate observations. I can't find a simple way to drop duplicates, and it seems that the PySpark `dropDuplicates()` function is unavailable in SparkR. For example, if I have the following `DataFrame`, how can I drop the 2nd and 4th rows based on the fact that `fullname` is duplicated?

```
newHires <- data.frame(name = c("Thomas", "Thomas", "Bill", "Bill"),
  surname = c("Smith", "Smith", "Taylor", "Taylor"),
  value = c(1.5, 1.5, 3.2, 3.2))
newHires <- withColumn(newHires, 'fullname', concat(newHires$name, newHires$surname))
```

```
|name    | surname | value | fullname  |
|--------|---------|-------|-----------|
|Thomas  | Smith   |  1.5  |ThomasSmith|
|Thomas  | Smith   |  1.5  |ThomasSmith|
|Bill    | Taylor  |  3.2  |BillTaylor |
|Bill    | Taylor  |  3.2  |BillTaylor |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function `dropDuplicates` in sparkR as well you can use as

```
dropDuplicates(newHire, "fullname")
```

Please refer [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/index.html)

Hope this helped!